# error=13, permission denied while running a .sh file through automation in eclipse

Tags: java

I am Creating a .sh file newly every time while running automation and while executing that file i am getting permission error always, for time being i am adding permission by running the below command in terminal

```
chmod u+x "filelocation"
```

Can someone help me to handle this issue permanently.

Comment: We can't help much without seeing your code, i.e. how you set the flags from Java, and how to run the shell script from Java.

Answer (score 2):

As you are always creating the new file, permissions must also be reassigned.

You can run `chmod u+x "filelocation"` from your code where you created the file to give permissions to the file.

You can reference https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/ on how to run shell commands from java using `ProcessBuilder`.